# Why does my boost::circular_buffer crash when accessed using an iterator?

Tags: c++, boost, circular-buffer

In the following program, when I access elements from the front of the circular buffer using `*(begin_iterator + index)` I get a crash. But if I access the same elements using `buffer[index]`, the crash is eliminated. (See the two commented lines below). Why does this happen?

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <thread>

auto buffer = boost::circular_buffer<int>(5000);

void f1()
{
    const auto N = 500;

    while (true) {

        // Make sure the buffer is never empty
        if (buffer.size() < N+1) {
            continue;
        }

        auto front = buffer.begin();

        volatile auto j = int{};
        for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
            // j = *(front + i);        // un-commenting this causes a crash
            // j = buffer[i];           // un-commenting this doesn't
        }

        buffer.erase_begin(N);
    }
}
void f2()
{
    while (true) {

        // Make sure the buffer is at most half-full.
        if (buffer.size() > buffer.capacity() / 2) {
            continue;
        }

        static auto k = 0;
        buffer.push_back(k++);
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::thread{f1};
    auto t2 = std::thread{f2};

    t1.join();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're experiencing [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you're reading and modifying the same object unsynchronized from multiple threads.

Coding it one way or another might eliminate the crash, but the program is still wrong.

If we add a mutex, then there's no crash anymore:

```
#include <boost/circular_buffer.hpp>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>

boost::circular_buffer<int> buffer(5000);
std::mutex mtx;

void f1()
{
    const auto N = 500;

    while (true) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        // Make sure the buffer is never empty
        if (buffer.size() < N + 1) {
            continue;
        }

        auto front = buffer.begin();

        volatile auto j = int{};
        for (auto i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
             j = *(front + i);        // is OK now
            // j = buffer[i];         
        }

        buffer.erase_begin(N);
    }
}
void f2()
{
    while (true) {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(mtx);

        // Make sure the buffer is at most half-full.
        if (buffer.size() > buffer.capacity() / 2) {
            continue;
        }

        static auto k = 0;
        buffer.push_back(k++);
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto t1 = std::thread{ f1 };
    auto t2 = std::thread{ f2 };

    t1.join();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. So it seems that I had too many assumptions about the implementation details of circular_buffer in my mind. I was assuming that because different threads seem to be acting on different parts of the buffer (the front and back), their actions should be thread-safe. You answer implies that this assumption is exactly what was wrong, right?

Comment: It's not about buffer elements. The buffer surely has internal pointers for start and end position, which you're sharing in multiple threads.